# How to configure nginx for 3 server backend on the same host?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have 3 servers that run in one domain and 3 ports:80,8080,8081, respectively.
How to set up a simple configuration of nginx as a proxy for these three servers ? Any one can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, that's very simple :)
this my config

```
  events {
     worker_connections  4096; 
     }

     http {

     upstream myproject {

      server  127.0.0.1:80;
      server  127.0.0.2:8080;
      server  127.0.0.2:8081;
     } 

     server { 

    listen 80;

    location / { 

     proxy_pass      http://myproject;

    }

    }
```

## hmin ham nemidony

Answer (score 1):

or this way , for one backend

```
 http {

 server { 

listen 80;

location / { 

 proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:80;

}

}
```